# nlog renderer for types other than the Layout (for target attributes)

Tags: layout, config, nlog, renderer

I am trying to configure mail target by params from app.config using custom renderer. My NLog Mail Target:

```xml
<target name="AlertMail" xsi:type="Mail"
  to="${mailTo}"
  from="${mailFrom}"
  html="true"
  encoding="${enc}"
  subject="[APPNAME][${mailEnv}][${instanceName}][${logger:uppercase=true}]"
  smtpServer="${smtpHost}"
  smtpAuthentication="${smtpAuth}"
  smtpUserName="${smtpUserName}"
  smtpPassword="${smtpPassword}"
  header="${mailHtmlHeader}${mailBodyHeader}"
  layout="${mailMessage}"
  footer="${mailBodyFooter}${mailHtmlFooter}"/>
```

NLog Variables:

```xml
<variable name="${enc}" value="${app-settings:default.encoding}" />
<variable name="${smtpAuth}" value="${app-settings:alerting.smtp.authentication}" />
```

NLog Layout Renderer:

```csharp
[LayoutRenderer("app-settings")]
public class AppSettingsRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    [RequiredParameter]
    [DefaultParameter]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        var param = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[this.Key];
        builder.Append(param);
    }
}
```

I'm getting error

```
Error when setting property 'Encoding' on Mail Target[AlertMail]
at NLog.Internal.PropertyHelper.SetPropertyFromString(Object o, String name, String value, ConfigurationItemFactory configurationItemFactory)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ConfigureObjectFromAttributes(Object targetObject, NLogXmlElement element, Boolean ignoreType)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseTargetElement(Target target, NLogXmlElement targetElement)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseTargetsElement(NLogXmlElement targetsElement)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseNLogElement(NLogXmlElement nlogElement, String baseDirectory)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseTopLevel(NLogXmlElement content, String baseDirectory)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.Initialize(XmlReader reader, String fileName, Boolean ignoreErrors)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration..ctor(String fileName)
at Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter..ctor(NameValueCollection properties) in D:\Project\GSJSJZB\GSJ_SJZB\Common.Logging.NLog\Logging\NLog\NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter.cs:line 109
```

and it's obviously because LayoutRenderer handling properties only type of Layout. The property smtpAuthentication has the same issue. How to workaround this limitation to use params from appconfig for types other than Layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue using custom Target derived from MailTarget:

```csharp
[Target("MyMail")]
class MyMailTarget : MailTarget
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Wrapper for enum to use placeholders
    /// </summary>
    [DefaultValue("None")]
    public Layout SmtpAuth { get; set; }

    protected override void Write(NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        Write(new[] {logEvent});
    }

    protected override void Write(NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo[] logEvents)
    {
        var renderedAuthType = SmtpAuth.Render(logEvents.Last().LogEvent);
        SmtpAuthenticationMode mode;
        if (Enum.TryParse(renderedAuthType, true, out mode))
            SmtpAuthentication = mode;
        else
        {
            InternalLogger.Warn("Could not convert '{0}' to SmtpAuthenticationMode, valid values are None, Basic and Ntlm.");
            throw new NLogRuntimeException(String.Format("Cannot render SmtpAuthentication. SmtpAuth = {0}", renderedAuthType));
        }
        base.Write(logEvents);
    }
}
```

Using:

```xml
<extensions>
  <add assembly="AssemplyNameWithMyMailTarget" />
</extensions>

<variable name="smtpAuth" value="${app-settings:alerting.SMTP.Authentication}"/>

<!-- smtpAuth - my custom attribute -->

<target name="AlertMail" xsi:type="MyMail"
  to="${mailTo}"
  from="${mailFrom}"
  subject="[APPNAME][ALERT][${mailEnv}][${instanceName}]"
  smtpServer="${smtpHost}"
  smtpAuth="${smtpAuth}" 
  smtpUserName="${smtpUserName}"
  smtpPassword="${smtpPassword}"
  layout="${longdate}${newline}${message}${newline}"
  />
```